# Call external Web Service using javascript CRM 2011 RU 12 (Rollup 12)

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

Until very recently we'd been using RU 11 within our Dynamics CRM 2011 application but have recently begun a project to eventually move to CRM 2015. We've upgraded to RU 12 and this is where things get fun!

I've managed to sort out a lot of the coding issues that were previously present but cannot for the life of me solve our issue of accessing an external web service, passing parameters along the way and retrieving data back.

At first I had trouble with the "CreateXmlHttp()" function but found a great answer online indicating that the following function would help:

```
function CreateXmlHttp()
{
    var ref = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ref = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE
        ref = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }            
    return ref;         
}
```

This worked fine and as expected, it would have appeared that I could now connect to the service.

However, I am not retrieving any data and this is the issue that is tying me up in knots.

As background, the following is my code to declare a few integer variables before POSTING the xml through to the webservice.

```
parseInt(lngLicensNr);
parseInt(lngNrOfUsers);
parseInt(lngAnnualWorkingTime);
parseInt(lngIncludedHours);
parseInt(productType);

if (licenceType == 100000000) {
    var licenseType = "ltUnlimitedMode";
    lngIncludedHours = 1000000;
}
if (licenceType == 100000001) {
    var licenseType = "ltHourlyMode";
}

if (lngLicensNr != null && lngNrOfUsers != null && lngAnnualWorkingTime != null && lngIncludedHours != null && productType != null && licenseType != null) {

    var errMsg = "";
    var errCount = 0;
    var xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    xml += "<soap:Body>";
    xml += "<GetBaseInstallationKey xmlns=\"http://www.keyservice.com/\">";
    xml += "<licensNr>" + lngLicensNr + "</licensNr>";
    xml += "<nrOfUsers>" + lngNrOfUsers + "</nrOfUsers>";
    xml += "<annualWorkingTime>" + lngAnnualWorkingTime + "</annualWorkingTime>";
    xml += "<includedHours>" + lngIncludedHours + "</includedHours>";
    xml += "<productType>" + baseProduct + "</productType>";
    xml += "<licenseType>" + licenseType + "</licenseType>";
    xml += "</GetBaseInstallationKey>";
    xml += "</soap:Body>";
    xml += "</soap:Envelope>";

    try {
        Request = CreateXmlHttp();
    } catch (ex) {
        alert("An error occured while accessing the webservice.\n\n1. " + ex.name + " \n " + ex.message + "\n\n");
        errCount = 1;
    }

    if (errCount == 0) {
        try {
            Request.open("POST", "http://web01:8080/KeyWebService/KeyWebService.asmx", false);
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("An error occured while accessing the webservice.\n\n2. " + ex.name + " \n " + ex.message + "\n\n");
            errCount = 1;
        }
    }

    if (errCount == 0) {
        try {
            Request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.keyservice.com/GetKey");
            Request.setRequestHeader("Host", "web01:8080");
            Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
            Request.send(xml);
            var xmlDoc = Request.responseXML;
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("An error occured while accessing the webservice.\n\n3. " + ex.name + " \n " + ex.message + "\n\n");
            errCount = 1;
        }
    }

    if (errCount == 0 || Request.responseXML != null) {
        baseKey = Request.responseXML.text;
    } else {
        baseKey = "No key generated";
    }
}

if (lngLicensNr == null || lngNrOfUsers == null || lngAnnualWorkingTime == null || lngIncludedHours == null || productType == null || licenseType == null) {
    alert('Not all parameters have been entered - it is not possible to generate a key without all parameters');
}
```

Prior to RU 12, the code worked absolutely fine and the last variable "baseKey" was retrieved from the web service.

However, the whole process works perfectly fine now in that it seems to connect ok but just does not retrieve a "baseKey" from the service.

I believe that the issue may be related to deprecated end points or schemas or even just deprecated code that returns and displays the value (i.e. var xmlDoc = Request.responseXML;) but I'm not sure where to resolve.

If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction it would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

we had similar requirement to call an external `Web-service` to retrieve the `latest contract` of a contact and show it on `Contact Form.`

We had our own definition of  `latest contract` that was implement in a webserivce. So i have to call that webservice on `Contact Form Load` and pull the data. I could not find an answer. So i am posting my workaround for this.

I had written a `plugin` that executes on the retrieve of `Contact`. From the plugin i had call the `Webservice` and updates the contact fields.

```
var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = 104857600; //200 MB unicode

StringBuilder URI = new StringBuilder();
URI.Append(crmRestWebServiceUrl).Append(webServiceMethod);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI.ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

//Serialize request object as JSON and write to request body
  if (latestMembershipRequest != null)
   {
     var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(latestMembershipRequest, stringBuilder);
     var requestBody = stringBuilder.ToString();
     request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
  var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
 streamWriter.Write(requestBody);
 streamWriter.Close();   
   }


  var response = request.GetResponse();

 //Read JSON response stream and deserialize
var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var responseContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
LatestMembershipResponse latestMembershipResponse = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<LatestMembershipResponse>(responseContent);

  ContactToUpdate["gr_membershiptitle"] = latestMembership.MembershipTitle;
  ContactToUpdate["gr_membershipstartdate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(latestMembership.MembershipStartDate);
  ContactToUpdate["gr_membershipenddate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(latestMembership.MembershipEndDate);
  ContactToUpdate["gr_membershipstatus"] = latestMembership.MembershipStatus;
  service.Update(ContactToUpdate);
```

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for answering although I'm not too sure it helps me on this occasion. Is .GetResponse() a standard function or is it a function that is defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @Mark it is the standard function to call a `Rest WebService`